# Elixir on docker cannot connect to postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, elixir, amazon-aurora

I am trying to deploy elixir application on Docker container, it is successfully deployed but when I run an API endpoint it shows following error

```
{
  errors: {
    detail: "Internal Server Error"
  }
}
```

after check logs `docker logs [CONTAINER_ID]` the following errors occurred (it cannot connect to database)

my database is on AWS Aurora and I am able to connect to it using pgadmin

```
18:21:26.624 [error] #PID<0.652.0> running ABC.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.651.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /api/v1/popular-searches/us/en
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) connection not available and request was dropped from queue after 2850ms. This means requests are coming in and your connection pool cannot serve them fast enough. You can address this by:

  1. Tracking down slow queries and making sure they are running fast enough
  2. Increasing the pool_size (albeit it increases resource consumption)
  3. Allowing requests to wait longer by increasing :queue_target and :queue_interval

See DBConnection.start_link/2 for more information

        (ecto_sql 3.5.3) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:751: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
        (ecto_sql 3.5.3) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:684: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute/5
        (ecto 3.5.5) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:229: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/4
        (ecto 3.5.5) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:17: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/3
        (ecto 3.5.5) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:157: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.one!/3
        (_api 0.1.1) lib/api_web/controllers/V1/cms_data_controller.ex:14: ApiWeb.V1.CMSDataController.get_popular_searches/2
        (_api 0.1.1) lib/_api_web/controllers/V1/cms_data_controller.ex:1: ApiWeb.V1.CMSDataController.action/2
        (_api 0.1.1) lib/_api_web/controllers/V1/cms_data_controller.ex:1: ApiWeb.V1.CMSDataController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
18:21:26.695 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.487.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
18:21:26.714 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.479.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
18:21:26.718 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.469.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres:5432): non-existing domain - :nxdomain
18:21:26.810 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.493.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (postgres:5432): non-existing domain - :
```

I have checked the env variables in the container which are correct, database URL is correct, my Docker file looks file this:

```
# base image elixer to start with
FROM elixir:1.13.4

# install hex package manager
RUN mix local.hex --force

RUN curl -o phoenix_new.ez https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phoenix_new.ez
RUN mix archive.install ./phoenix_new.ez

RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV MIX_ENV=prod
ENV PORT=4000

ENV DATABASE_URL=postgres://[URL]

RUN mix local.rebar --force
RUN mix deps.get --only prod
RUN mix compile

RUN mix phx.digest
CMD mix phx.server
```

after building the images i start it like this:

```
docker build . -t [name]
docker run --name [name] -p 4000:4000 -d [name]
```

What am I doing wrong?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify with iex that your ENV is set? Maybe the ENV in the dockerfile is only for compilation NOT for runtime.

Comment: the other way to check with docker is by setting the URL env in the runtime
`docker run --env DATABASE_URL=postgres://[URL] --name [name] -p 4000:4000 -d [name]`

Comment: Thanks i figured i had a special character in my password, that was causing it, i removed special character from password and it worked